# titanium show only number pad in ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

is it possible to show only number pad with decimal in ipad.

i have used this code and i am getting correct in iphone but not in ipad Why?

Here is my textfield.

```
   var enterValuetextfield = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    value : 'Enter Value',
    width : osname == 'ipad' ? '50%' : '90%',
    backgroundColor : '#32302D',
    color : 'white',
    borderRadius : 10,
    keyboardToolbarHeight : 30,
    paddingLeft:10,
    borderColor : "#AEB0B2",
    height : osname == 'ipad' ? 60 : 50,
    keyboardToolbar : [send],
    keyboardType : Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_DECIMAL_PAD,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think working fully fine.Arent you seeing this type of keyboard

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7edgljl2z40tfs0/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Apr%2012%2C%202014%2010.34.23%20PM.png

Thanks

Comment: @wahab is there any solution for this to show only number pad?

Comment: Nope i think you want to say that it should show only 1,2,3,4 not any other sign thats not possible